# How to safely destructure a JavaScript object in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to pull out attributes from a JavaScript object (below) but want to protect myself from either the object being null or undefined as well as the properties not existing. That is, I want the values to just be undefined and not have the JavaScript error.

```
const {id,username,userFirstName,userLastName} = attendeeResults;
```

Comment: If the properties don't exist on the object, `undefined` is precisely what destructuring will give you, no need to precaution against errors.

Answer (score 6):

You can use logical operators to achieve that:

```js
const nullObject = null;
const { foo, bar } = nullObject || {};

console.log(foo, bar);
```

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript allow you to define default value when destructuring an object.
For example:

```
const {id: 0,username:'',userFirstName:'',userLastName:''} = attendeeResults;
```

But destruncturing throws an error if your `attendeeResults` object is null or undefined.

Comment: "*I want the values to just be undefined*". Not `0` or `''`

Comment: If the key doesn't exists in the object, destructruring will give you undefined, default values is used for preventing undefined value, but it's optional. Only destruncturing a null or undefined object throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done this way:

```js
const {id, username, ...rest} = {id: 10, username: 'u', firstname:'behzad',lastname:'besharati'};


console.log(id,username,rest);
```

Comment: OP doesn't need rest properties.

Comment: i think this is still a good answer exploring the concept deeper

Answer (score 0):

building on the response by José Salgado. Ensure to use `??` Nullish Coalescing Operator since you are actually checking for null

```js
const { foo, bar } = null ?? {};

console.log(foo, bar);
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use the following, Please notice that i omitted username in the `attendee` to show that it keeps the null value.

```js
const attendeeResults = { id: 1, userFirstName: 'John', userLastName: 'Smith'}
const obj = {
  id: null,
  username: null,
  userFirstName: null,
  userLastName: null
};
Object.assign(obj, attendeeResults);
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: That's better than what I came up with it because I don't have to declare everything, but I was hoping for a more compact solution.

Comment: You should probably create a class to represent your user model and than just instantiate a new class and copy values if they exist.